# Amazon Cognito doesn't send SMS to the different region phone number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have a problem about Amazon Cognito.
My Cognito region is eu-west-2, SNS region is also eu-west-2. And my SNS is already enabled to production and account spending limit is 50 USD.

The cognito sends SMS to the US/UK and European phone numbers, but it doesn't send SMS to the Asian countries (UAE, PH, etc).

My Questions are:

1. Is it impossible to send SMS to the different region?
2. How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SMS regulations vary a lot between countries, which leads to a myriad of possible issues.

I'd recommend that you turn on [CloudWatch logs for SMS deliveries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sns-viewing-cloudwatch-logs). This will produce error messages for any SMS delivery attempts and should provide you with hints as to why these messages are not delivered. Once you have those, you'll have an easier time figuring out exactly what is going wrong.